# How to develop my own sms Gateway?

Tags: c#, .net, sms, smpp, sms-gateway

I intend to develop an SMS gateway in c#, but i am doubtful about it's feasibility, because my initial research had shown that an SMS gateway had to cover for protocol differences.

So what exactly a gateway had to do, further if i use SMPP, so is it possible to send/receive SMS to/from any number in the world by simply using SMPP ?

Comment: Did you find any way to develop your own SMS gateway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "true" SMS gateway will need to generate an SMPP request in the the correct format (yes there are several types like CIMD & EMI) and dispatch it to the mobile networks SMSMC for sending.

You would need a direct connection to, and contract with the network(s) you use on the back end. The countries you would be able to send to will depend on the what the network provider supports/allows.

Creating one is difficult & expensive, why not use an SMS aggregator who have already done all the hard work, for example http://www.clickatell.com/.

Comment: thanks for the response, i have question, The variations as you mentioned like CIMD, EMI and others lie inside the boundary of SMPP or they are separate competing protocols? I mean, Is SMPP the only protocol to cover when one needs to talk to SMSC's or there are other competing protocols as well ?

Comment: CIMD etc are separate from SMPP

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about creating a gateway but I'm fairly sure that the answer to *so is it possible to send/receive SMS to/from any number in the world by simply using SMPP* is no. I looked at a few online SMS services a year or two ago and all of the ones I looked at listed networks/countries where messages could/couldn't be sent to.

Comment: thanks for the response, it seems like, once an sms is communicated to SMSC than it can reach to only those destination's which current SMSC can send it to, which are always limited.